# What Went Wrong When Writing to a Database File in C

Tags: c

I am working on a home work assignment. Here is the actual assignment:

Hardware Inventory – Write a database to keep track of tools, their cost and number. Your program should initialize hardware.dat to 100 empty records, let the user input a record number, tool name, cost and number of that tool. Your program should let you delete and edit records in the database. The next run of the program must start with the data from the last session.

After initializing hfPtr appropriately, I am getting a logic error that is inhibiting the program from actually updating the file. XCode is not actually throwing an error but it is not updating correctly.

Here is what is happening:

> Enter your choice
>   
> 1 - List of all tools
>   
> 2 - Update an existing tool
>   
> 3 - Add a new tool
>   
> 4 - Delete a tool
>   
> 5 - End program
>   
> ? 3
>   
> Enter record number to create (1-100) : 1
>   
> Enter tool name, quantity, cost
>   
> ?Screwdriver
>   
> 5
>
> Enter your choice
>   
> 1 - List of all tools
>   
> 2 - Update an existing tool
>   
> 3 - Add a new tool
>   
> 4 - Delete a tool
>   
> 5 - End program
>   
> ?

It just loops around again right after the quantity has been entered. Nothing is actually written to the DB.

What exactly is it that I am missing or doing wrong? How can I correct this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


struct hardwareData
{
    int recordNum;
    char toolname[20];
    int quantity;
    double cost;
};

/* prototypes */
int enterChoice( void );
void textFile( FILE *readPtr );
void updateRecord( FILE *fPtr );
void newRecord( FILE *fPtr );
void deleteRecord( FILE *fPtr );

FILE *hfPtr;

void newRecord( FILE *fPtr )
{
    struct hardwareData hardware = { 0, "", 0, 0.0 };
    int piece;
    FILE *hfPtr = fopen("hardware.txt","rb+");

     printf( "Enter record number to create (1-100) : " );
    scanf( "%d", &piece);

    fseek( fPtr, (piece - 1) * sizeof( struct hardwareData ), SEEK_SET );

    fread( &hardware, sizeof( struct hardwareData ), 1, fPtr );

    if ( hardware.recordNum != 0 ) 
    {
        printf( "Record already exists.\n", hardware.recordNum );
    }
    else 
    { 
        printf( "Enter tool name, quantity, cost\n?" );
        scanf("%s%d%.2lf", hardware.toolname, &hardware.quantity, &hardware.cost);

        hardware.recordNum = piece;
        fseek(fPtr, (hardware.recordNum-1) * sizeof( struct hardwareData), SEEK_SET);

        fwrite( &hardware, sizeof( struct hardwareData), 1, hfPtr);
    } 
}
```

Comment: debug and post only the relevant code with the relevant issue

Comment: "get an error and then it hangs indefinitely and doesn't do anything" - what's the error? Can you step through in XCode to work out where the error comes from and which line it's on, and what it's doing when it hangs?

Comment: "get an error" is absolutely meaningless to us unless you explain what **error** you received. Have you made any effort to debug this yourself to figure out why it's not working? Have you at least narrowed the problem down to a specific area of the code? This is not a site for "Here's a bunch of stuff I wrote. It doesn't work. Figure out the problem and how to fix it - be back later to pick up your work. Thx." type questions.

Comment: I have made efforts to try and debug this myself. I realize that I suck at asking questions and I have reformatted and rephrased my question.

Comment: Did you notice you have both a global and function local `FILE *hfPtr;`? In the function, you don't initialize it. Another reason to *not* use globals.

Comment: 1) Post `enterChoice()` code 2) Check the return value from all `scanf()` calls.

Answer (score 0):

```
fwrite( &hardware, sizeof( struct hardwareData), 1, hfPtr);
```

Where are you initializing your local file pointer `hfptr` hence the crash.
Inside

```
void newRecord( FILE *fPtr )
```

You have a local variable `hfPtr` and that is not initialized.

The pointer is not pointing to anything, you need to do something like.

```
FILE *hfPtr = fopen("file","w");
```

Comment: Aren't I initializing the pointer as a global variable before my main function?

Comment: Thank you. I have made my revision and I feel silly for missing what I did.

Comment: @zacheybuu np did that fix your issue?

Comment: It did fix the initial issue but I am running into a logical issue now. I have edited the question. It is not writing properly.

Answer (score -1):

cFptr will always be null. When you fail to open the file for the first time you dont update that pointer. You should either return the file handle from the textFile function or re-open the file in main

But mainly - learn to use xcode debugger and step through your program line by line